# Compatible USB RF receiver for Boxee remote to use on PC / Mac?

Tags: remote, boxee

I have a spare Boxee remote, and wanted to use on PC / Mac but require a compatible USB RF receiver, does anyone know of any compatible ones? (It would save me from having to purchase another complete Boxee remote w/ dongle).

I had a look on Google / Boxee forums to no avail.